# Goutte Selectors on Markup that may or may not be present

Tags: php, xpath, css-selectors, goutte

I'm sure this is simple but I'm struggling to get it right.  I have the following markup:

```
<div id="container">
   <h3>Instructions</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   <h3>Directions</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
   <h3>Warnings</h3>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Any of the three elements might be missing and they can be in any order, I want to be able to extract the text in the p tags using goutte and know which one I'm dealing with.

I've tried variations of the following without success:

```
$node->filter('div#container h3')->each(function (Crawler $node) {
   switch ($node->text() {
      case 'Instructions':
         //$instructions = $node->filter('p')->text();
         //$instructions = $node->closest('p')->text();
         $instructions = $node->parents()->filter('p')->text()
      break;
    //etc....
   }
});
```

I've also tried using xpath to get preceding-siblings but can't get it right trying things along the lines of

```
$node->filterXPath("/div[preceding-sibling::h3[normalize-space() = 'Instructions']]");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like Crawler has a way of traversing to the next immediate sibling of an element so you may need to use XPath. Use the `following-sibling::` axis with a `[position() = 1]` predicate to limit it to just the very next p that comes after the h3 you want:

```
$node->filterXPath("/div/h3[normalize-space() = 'Instructions']/following-sibling::p[position() = 1]");
```

Answer (score -1):

In the **each** loop, why you use "crawler" in the parameter?? you just need to give $node to function and i think it is making problem!!

Comment: Because $node is an instance of Crawler?